# initialize lagged fibonacci generator

Tags: generator, fibonacci

I have a question about initialization parameter of `LFG`.

Say I need to generate a random integer less than 2^32. I can use a popular pair like `j = 7, k = 10, m=2^32`.

So I can calculate `S[n]=S[n-j]+S[n-k]` iteratively.

My question is how many times should I iterate? Does it satisfy the random criterion if iterating time is small?